# Preferred way to dynamically update table field with jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking for some type of 'best practice' or 'most accepted' type of solution for dynamically updating a field in a table.

For instance, a user is shown a field for "Quantity Open" with a value of 4.  They perform some AJAX operation that changes the "Quantity Open" value in the database to 3.

Does one usually create some server-side function for pulling the updated information?

Do you return it the new value as part of the AJAX return and in the jQuery's $.ajax().done() method and create a helper to update the field that was modified?

I feel the latter is the better option, but definitely would love some feedback.

Comment: If the new value is coming as a result of some server-side operation, then return that value and set it in the `.success` AJAX method.

Comment: Why is this such a "useless question" that it received 2 down votes?

Comment: I'd like to know that too...  Maybe because I didn't include a jsfiddle. :P

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there's a "best practice" in this case, but rather, what suits you better in the situation. If you know for a fact that you can rely on your users having JavaScript enabled, I'd recommend using [jQuery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        // Reflect the changes here
        // e.g. update the Quantity Open field
    }
})
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data
}).done(function () {
    // Reflect the changes here
    // e.g. update the Quantity Open field
});
```

Whichever you prefer.

Comment: I thought they were deprecating the success method in favor of using the done method?  That's what I'm thinking is the better solution, return the changed variable in the AJAX response and then update the fields with the returned data.

Comment: @KyleJohnson You are half right there: the _callback-manipulation functions_ (for example. `.error`, `.success`, etc.) are indeed being deprecated in favor of the more universal [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) pattern, but the `success` parameter to the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method is _not_ being deprecated. You can use the `success` parameter or the [.done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) deferred method as they are both valid an acceptable. (I prefer the `success` parameter form).

Comment: Gotcha!  I saw the `success` parameter in their documentation, but it looks like it behaves identically to the `.done` deferred method.  Is there a difference between the parameter and the deferred method?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use

```
$.post(test.php,{data:test},function(data)
{
});
```